# white space being added to parallax div, using parallax.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a website I built using parallax.min.js on top of WordPress, and I am having a very weird issue. I've spent probably 4 hours on this and have concluded that a large white space is being added to the bottom of a div you can see in below screenshot.
[image]

when I view code I can see the white space is being added to only one of the parallax divs `.para_block` - the very last div block on that home page on top of the footer.

the dev site is located here - [bloompeach.mybrowsertest.com](http://bloompeach.mybrowsertest.com) - I know this is a long shot but I want to see if anyone smarter than me can see something easy I am leaving out.

what is crazy about this is I am using the same code on a site I built a few weeks ago located here - truffles.accountsupport.com - and I am unable to replicate the issue there. which makes this even more confusing.

I appreciate your time and energy it takes to review my post and the dev site, in an effort to fix this. heck if you can figure this out I'll buy you a coffee or a six-pack I am so exhausted trying to solve this.

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle or demo link ?

Comment: yes demo link is in the post. third paragraph from bottom

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the `height` of `.parallax-window`, now its look better

```
.parallax-window {
   min-height:837px;
}
```

Comment: i tried that previously. all that does is add more padding to the top of the div and does not clear the extra white space issue being added iin the .para_block. note that the white space is being added to the .para_block and not the .white_block div.